# Declaring an array of int in xtend

Tags: arrays, int, xtend

How can I declare an array of int in xtend?

I've tried ArrayList but I get the error "The primitive 'int' cannot be a type argument".

Comment: ,I am missing the code you tried

Answer (score 8):

Please refer to the docs for details, but essentially its something along these lines:

```
val int[] x = newIntArrayOfSize(5)
```

or if you want to define an array literal:

```
val int[] x = #[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I am still getting error, the method newIntArrayOfSize is not defined for the type calculatorClass. I have already imported java.lang.Object. What library should I import?

Comment: The method newIntArrayOfSize is new in Xtend 2.4. Which version do you use?